# Error in opencv_creatsamples : free() :corrupted unsorted chunks:

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu-16.04

i am trying to generate positive images to haar training using one positive image and opencv_createsamples. I am using ubuntu 16.4 in virtual box, update and upgrade the system and i installed the last libopencv-dev. When run the opencv_createsamples instruction i get this Error:

```
***Error in 'opencv_createsamples': free(): corrupted unsorted chunks:0x08b48d28***.

=====Backtrace:=======
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x67257)[0xb6e43257]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/....
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I was getting the same error when I was trying to train my model using `opencv_traincascade`. After searching the internet for a while, I found out the problem was with the background descriptor file, which in your case is **bg.txt**, the file you're using in Ubuntu must've created on Windows platform. Try creating a copy of the same file in Ubuntu by creating an empty file and then simply copying the content of the file and giving it a different name under the same directory. It should definitely work. Cheers. For any further issues comment down below.